# Перевод на новую строку при удалении

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2015, форматирование-кода

Подскажите как Visual Studio Code сделать чтобы когда я нажимаю backspace строка поднималась выше, и не приходилось много раз нажимать чтобы удалить все пробелы. Нажал backspace и все пробелы убрались и строка перешла на верх.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"строка перешла на верх"* Не понял, наверх - это куда? В конец предыдущей строки?

Comment: так точно, в конец предыдущей, сейчас приходится нажимать backspace много раз чтобы убрать все пробелы и попасть в конец строки предыдущей

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Home</kbd> (если нужно), зажать Shift, <kbd>▲</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, отпустить Shift, <kbd>Space</kbd> (или, если не нужен пробел между строчками, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>).

Можно найти себе плагин для записи макросов, и назначить на это хоткей.

Answer (score 0):

Это вопрос как пользоваться удалением в vs code. Я удаляю строку следующим образом. Ставлю позицию курсора в конец нужной строки, выделяю фрагмент кода который мне не нужен вплоть до начала нужной мне строки и нажимаю enter. Мне это помогает и вам советую.

Comment: спс . за совет. но я скорее имел ввиду настройку, которая за это отвечает. в phpstorm работает из коробки, не важно сколько пробелов позади курсора - он все равно все удалит, и не нужно выделять ничего